# Add custom view cordova/ionic

Tags: android, cordova

Before cordova 4, i was able to addView using root variable.
But since cordova v5, the variable is deprecated and cant get it work. its because cordova wont use a linearlayout anymore.

What i've tried:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.addView(appView.getView());
setContentView(layout);
```

But the app crashes at startup.

Carsh Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx/com.xx.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

So i tried to remove it but still no success:

```
((View)appView.getParent()).removeView(appView);
```

Error:

```
/PATH/MainActivity.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    ((View)appView.getParent()).removeView(appView);
                  ^
    symbol:   method getParent()
    location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    1 error
    FAILED
```

Comment: Put the crash message error.

Comment: @alessadro thanks for heads up, added the crash log

Comment: im still looking for a way ... !